# How to copy a character from one string to a different string?

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, string

This is my code : -

```
void sumNumbersInString(char j[100]) {
    int count = 0;
    char list[100];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (j[i] == '0' || j[i] == '1' || j[i] == '2' || j[i] == '3' || j[i] == '4' || j[i] == '5' || j[i] == '6' || j[i] == '7' || j[i] == '8' || j[i] == '9'){
            count++;
            strncpy(list,j, 1);
            printf("%c\n", j[i]);
        }

    }
    printf("Count = %d\n", count);
    printf("Final String: %s\n", list);


}

int main() {
    char s[100] = "hello100supach4ier78hu";
    sumNumbersInString(s);
    return 0;
}
```

So what I want to do is Once I seperate the numbers from the string I want to put the numbers in a different string.. How do I that..PLz help me

Comment: use isdigit(j[i]) to check if it is a digit. (include ctype.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
list[count] = j[i];
count++;
```

You can also use "isdigit()" to test number digits on Unix/Linux systems. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit

However if you want to use strncpy:

```
strncpy(list + count, j + i, 1);
count++;
```

Also, as pointed out by @Mohan be sure that the list is NULL terminated. Your initialisation is correct because string literals are NULL terminated as long as there is room for the terminating character. Otherwise it is safe to initialise list:

```
char list[100] = {0};
```

Comment: Still result will not correct because in `list` NULL termination is essential.  I think there is no meaning in doing `strncpy`.....if copying single char....

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for the comment, inserting a terminating char is always a good practice, however, I don't see why do you think that here is essential. The size of the array is fixed and we are copying elements one by one.

Comment: Initialise the `char list[100] = {0};` to print correct string......in case if it is not initialised to NULL and also not NULL terminated then result will be Undefined. Try it in VS.

Comment: @Mohan I think that your suggestion is good and I updated the answer, however string literals are null terminated and so the initialisation of list in the code is correct as long as the size of list is equal to the number of char in the literals + 1

Answer (score 1):

Initialise the  `char list[100] = {0};` to print correct string.

Use assignment statement(not required `strncpy`) because you are testing one by one char in string .... and increment pointer of final list.

Working code...

```
void sumNumbersInString(char j[100]) {
    int count = 0;
    char list[100] = {0};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (j[i] == '0' || j[i] == '1' || j[i] == '2' || j[i] == '3' || j[i] == '4' || j[i] == '5' || j[i] == '6' || j[i] == '7' || j[i] == '8' || j[i] == '9'){

            //strncpy(list,j[i], 1);
           list[count]=j[i];
            count++;
            printf("%c\n", j[i]);
        }

    }
    printf("Count = %d\n", count);
    printf("Final String: %s\n", list);


}

int main() {
    char s[100] = "hello100supach4ier78hu";
    sumNumbersInString(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few minor modifications should do

```
void sumNumbersInString(char j[100]) {
    int count = 0;
    char list[100] = {0,}; // clean string
    int i, idx; // idx to keep track of final list length
    for (i = 0, idx = 0; i < 100; i++){

        if ( j[i] >= '0' && j[i] <= '9' ) {
            count++;
        } else {
            list[idx] = j[i];
            idx ++;
        }

    }
    printf("Count = %d\n", count);
    printf("Final String: %s\n", list);


}
```